# How would I implement enhanced conversion on Gtag?

Tags: google-ads-api, gtag.js

The client has requested the implementation of an event snippet on their website. This snippet involves adding a code snippet that sends hashed customer data for matching. Additionally, they have asked to include the parameter **"{'allow_enhanced_conversions': true}"** to the config line of the global site tag, which should trigger across all pages.

After implementing these changes, the resulting code looks as follows:

```
<head>
<!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
<script type="text/plain"  async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-12345"></script>

<script type="text/plain"">
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

    $(document).ready(function() {
    var userEmail = $("#email").val();
     gtag('set', 'user_data', {
    "email": userEmail,
      });
    });

    gtag('config', 'AW-12345', {'allow_enhanced_conversions': true});
    gtag('config', 'AW-12346', {'allow_enhanced_conversions': true});
</script>
```

However, the client has reported that the implementation has failed. Additionally, they have mentioned the absence of the ****"em" **parameter** in the Network Tab. I would appreciate assistance in resolving this issue.

Comment: hey Have you got implementation of this question?